# p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, netty, spark-notebook

I compiled spark-notebook from sources and am getting an error when trying to run it. Something is wrong with netty version.

Well, there are a lot of components in spark-notebooks. And those components require different netty versions. I tried to force sbt to use some specific version like

```
libraryDependencies += "io.netty" % "netty" % "3.6.3.Final" force()
```

But it didn't make the trick. Any idea how to resolve it?

BTW, netty 3.2.5 comes from org.jboss.netty.netty-3.2.5.Final.jar. Also there are netty artifacts from io.netty: io.netty.netty-3.6.3.Final.jar. Yeah, it's a kind of mess :-)

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest.headers()Lorg/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders;
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.getHeaders(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:366) ~[play_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62) ~[netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104) ~[netty-3.2.5.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302) ~[netty-3.2.5.Final.jar:na]
```